# axios not working for local API's without internet

Tags: react-native, axios

We are using axios in react native and we have a on-premise environment in one of our client, the scenario is:

1. If internet is connected Axios is able to make web service calls.
2. Without internet Axios is failing to connect to local API's
3. We are not using IP and Port, we are using host name (ex. api.abc.io/)
4. Same API's is working fine in device browser.

Comment: How is the system supposed to resolve hostnames without DNS?

Comment: @Phil, But then how it is working in browser?

Comment: Is it? You didn't say anything about that. Could be local DNS cache. What's the TTL on those domain names?

Comment: Also, what **exactly** do you mean by _"no internet"_? If you disable WiFi on a phone it will use the cellular network which won't be able to connect to anything local

Comment: I don't think its cache, because we are able to login and change configurations.

Comment: I said DNS, not browser cache

Comment: its a Tablet Kiosk application, without cellular network, with internet all API's are accessible through react native Kiosk app,

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to first confirm if you are able to reach the remote SQL server from your own and what's the response time from the other server. If everything seems fine and if both servers are in the same region, ask DigialOcean if it's possible for the two server to communicate in the private network instead making a connection through a public  IPs. Finally, if you are still experiencing this issue, I would suggest reaching their support and explaining this issue. They should be able to help if it's a "managed"
service.

Axios should have nothing to do with the explained issue. It really depends where your local API is being accessed. In order to ensure that you will be able to properly access the API host on your local machine, then try:

1. Use "localhost" for your API's location
2. Should you decide to use a custom host, then open your machine's so-called "hosts" file and add:

127.0.0.1 your-custom-host.com

This way, your machine will not need to search for DNS and your custom host will automatically be loaded from your localhost.